# AlertDialog title with component?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gui

Is it possible for the title in the `AlertDialog` to be a custom `View`?

I would like to add an edit `Button` on the right side of the title bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `AlertDialog` there is a method called [`setCustomTitle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html#setCustomTitle%28android.view.View%29) which you can pass custom view.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Didn't see that there.

Comment: When I add the custom view, the white line that goes after it disappears. Is there any way to get it back?